# Apache2 SetEnvIf Origin did not work

Tags: apache-2.4

I did not understand Apache 2 configuration, when I use

```
SetEnvIf Origin "^http(s)?://(.+\.)?(example\.com)$" origin_is=$0 
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{origin_is}e env=origin_is
```

That nevertimes add/set header Access-Control-Allow-Origin

When I use only

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "www.example.com"
```

that add/set header for every request

I need to set CORS dynamically, but I don't understand why Apache did not do it. Please, help.

Comment: Same problem here... I found that `Origin` is not set.